# Memory cleaning after navigation from large pivot.

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, mvvm-light

I have a master-detail pivot. Pivot contains 5 PivotItems, each of them has dozen of items. Every item has details page.

Now I noted that it is pretty memory-consuming. So I'm considering ways to decrease memory usage.

- I moved loading of PivotItems to IndexChanged event (all pivot items are inherited from base pivot class, and Pivot calls their OnPivotItemActivated(), where all initialization is done).
- Now I'm considering to upload all PivotItem's content from memory while moving to details page. How can I do that? Just by setting ItemsList to null?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to call

```
GC.Collect()
```

This will call the garbage collector and purge all unused objects from memory.This is also a bad idea.

The Long Answer:

.Net is a managed memory environment.  This means that it will automatically reclaim memory when it needs more.  .Net reclaims memory by running its Garbage Collector.  Here's what the garbage collector does:

1. It stops every executing thread in your app
2. It checks every single object in your app to see if it's referenced or being used by the CPU.
3. Those objects that aren't in use are removed from memory and the remaining objects are given new memory addresses so that your apps memory is in a single, continuous, block.

So, .Net will reclaim memory when it needs it so you don't need to worry about it.

If you really want to do it manually do it at a point where the user expects the app to pause such as:

- Saving data
- Moving from screen X to screen Y

Comment: The thing what i'm worrying about - is keeping references on some non-used objects via events, like in this case: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/02/01/memory-profiling-for-application-performance.aspx
So, the main question is: if ItemsList = null would be enough, or i should also run through the list and set all image sources to null?
Also, probably, i should try to call GC.Collect() only in debug mode, and see what happens.

Comment: If the issue is that you've got references on objects via events then GC.Collect won't work because you've got a reference to the object.  When you're throwing away objects you'll need to remove your references to events as part of your cleanup.

Comment: But is there any references, that appears automatically? Also, what is the most effective way to remove all events subscription? Just to unsubscribe inside of the event? But what if event would never happen?